# How do you query two variables in order to return one result?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a database with columns assigned username, datePro, and quantity.  $datePro is a DATE that a certain $quantity of material is produced from $username.  I'm trying to query results to echo the $quantity of material that is produced during a certain month from $username.

I've experimented and searched for help already posted but cannot seem to figure this out on my own.  Any guidance is appreciated. here's what I have...

```
$resultDate = mysql_query ("SELECT datePro FROM power WHERE username = '$username' ") or die(mysql_error()) ;

$resultQuant = mysql_query("SELECT quantity FROM power WHERE username = '$username' ") or die(mysql_error()) ;

$datePro = mysql_fetch_row($resultDate);
$quantity = mysql_fetch_row($resultQuant);

if ($datePro = '%Y-01-%d') echo $quantity;
```

Comment: When comparing things with an `if` statement, always be sure to use `==` instead of `=`.  The way you have it written there, your if statement will ALWAYS return true, AND it will change the value of $datePro.  Definitely not what you're after!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after this:

```
$queryObj = mysql_query ("SELECT datePro, quantity  FROM power WHERE username = '$username' ") or die(mysql_error()) ;

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryObj );


if ($row['datePro'] == '%Y-01-%d') echo $row['quantity'];
```

Comment: I thought I could use this to retrieve particular months like...      if ($row['datePro'] = '%Y-01-%d') echo $row['quantity'];
if ($row['datePro'] = '%Y-02-%d') echo $row['quantity'];    for january, february etc. but it's returning same numerical value.  Any thoughts??

Comment: Please refer to my comment on the original post: `=` is doing something different than `==`.  When you use `=` in an if statement, you are not evaluating a condition, you are changing the value of one of your variables! Check out this document for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$resultAll = mysql_query ("SELECT datePro, quantity FROM power WHERE username = '$username' ") or die(mysql_error()) ;

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // datePro
echo $row[1]; // quantity
```

you can select both from power at the sametime

Answer (score 0):

If you can have multiple rows for the same datePro and username, then you can use SUM to total all entries:

> SELECT sum(quantity) where username='$username' and datePro=date($dateToLookup)

(The date comparison will depend on how you store the date in the table.)

if there can be only one, then

> SELECT quantity where username='$username' and datePro=date($dateToLookup)

Both will return one row, with one field, which you can output or store.